# time complexity of the thin BDCSVD contained in the eigen library

Tags: c++, eigen, svd

I would like to know the complexity of the thin BDCSVD in the c++ library "eigen" in Landau / big-O notation. However, I cannot find anything mentioning the complexity of the eigen implementation. My problem is that I do not know if this kind of SVD is standard enough to say that: "Ok, BDCSVD has this complexity. So, eigen implemented it with this complexity." or does it depend on the implementation?

Comment: The BDCSVD implementation Eigen uses is based on [Ming Gu, Stanley C. Eisenstat: A Divide-and-Conquer Algorithm for the Bidiagonal SVD,  SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications, 1995, Vol. 16, No. 1 : pp. 79-92](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/S0895479892242232). Maybe you can find something there.

Comment: @dtell Thanks for your comment. How do you know Eigen's implementation is based on that? I looked for it, but did not find anything.